# How to determine if a subscription notification come from a test account in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-cloud-pubsub

When a subscription notification from an inapp product (using real-time PUB/SUB) reach our server, how can we know if that notification came from a test purchase? In the Google documentation said that the PUB/SUB test notifications have an attribute as testNotification but this attribute only shows when the notification was created in the Cloud Platform, but this attribute doesn't appear when the notification was a subscription notification.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the documentation you're referring to?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications.html in JSON Specification

Comment: @EvelinPonce did you ever find an answer to this? I am trying to solve the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the Pub/Sub notification:

- Base64-decode the payload's `message.data`, parse the JSON, and extract `packageName`, `subscriptionNotification.subscriptionId` and `subscriptionNotification.purchaseToken`. [See documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications#json_specification).
- send a get request with those 3 items to the Android Publisher Subscription Purchase API. [See documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions).
- If it is a test subscription, the response will contain `purchaseType: 0`.